# As a dual citizen (Australia+UK), can I increase my allowable time in the US by switching between my two passports?

Tags: esta, us-visa-waiver-program, dual-nationality

I have Australian and British passports. I intend to fly to the US in a couple of months, but between traveling in the US and the UK, I will be in North America for more than 90 days.

If I enter the US on my Australian passport, spend a couple of months traveling, then go to Canada, could I re-enter the US using my British passport? (Yes, I know I would need to have an ESTA for both passports).

Cheers.

Comment: Last I looked, the UK was not a part of "North America"

Comment: Didn't suggest it was.

Comment: But your mention of the UK is a little confusing. If you're going to the UK  and then back to north America, your trip might be allowable under the VWP, depending on the dates.  If it's not allowable under the VWP, you should consider whether to apply for a B-2 visa.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general, no. The admission policies of virtually all countries (including the US) apply to *people*, not to *passports*.

In applying for an ESTA, you are required to disclose all other citizenships you hold. Your plan would quickly be discovered.